# How to combine binary (PDF-) file chunks retrieved via a get function from an API

Tags: typescript, pdf, get, xmlhttprequest

Ive written a function which uses [xmlhttprequest-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest-ts) and should help with asynchronously getting a pdf from an api.

That PDF gets then send to a frontend afterwards, where its unfortunately displayed empty.
I would guess that I somehow need to merge the single data chunks I receive, but I have no clue what to do after trying out a multitude of ways.

For Example Buffer.from() + Buffer.concat() results in an empty buffer Printed out after the promise was resolved. The seemingly closest solution I had, is the following, where i just add up a binary string:

```
export async function getFile(resourceUrl: string, apiPath: string, responseType:string, token?: string, basicId?:string, apiKey?:string,  ): Promise<any>{
  try {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", resourceUrl + apiPath, true);
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(apiKey)){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("api-key", apiKey);
    } else if(!isNullOrUndefined( token) && isNullOrUndefined(basicId)){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    } else if(!isNullOrUndefined( token) && !isNullOrUndefined(basicId)){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Buffer.from(basicId + ":" + token).toString('base64'));
    }

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", responseType);
    
    let binaryString = ""; // initial binary string
    
    xhr.onload =  function (){
        try{
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {
              console.log("Code: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText +  "; Request success"  );
                
              binaryString = binaryString + xhr.responseText; //adding up binary string
            } else {
              console.log("Code: " + xhr.status + ": " +  xhr.statusText + "; "  + xhr.responseText);
              reject(new ErrorModule.xmlHttpServiceError(xhr.responseText, xhr.status , xhr.statusText, xhr.responseText ));
            }
        } catch(err){
          reject(err);
        }
    }

    xhr.onloadend = function (){
        try {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {

              resolve(binaryString); // returning binary string
            } else {
              console.log("Code: " + xhr.status + ": " +  xhr.statusText + "; "  + xhr.responseText);
              reject(new ErrorModule.xmlHttpServiceError(xhr.responseText, xhr.status , xhr.statusText, xhr.responseText ));
            }
          } catch(err){
            reject(err);
          }
      }
      
    xhr.send();

    });
} catch(err){
throw new Error(err);
}
```

}

When I print out the binary string after resolving, you can clearly see that there are multiple of chunks after each other in the following pattern (taken from the end of the string):

```
C}O�����D.��w�#n]:ީ��qqUX��N+��;�RD����]��}�_ܝ�%�/
                                             �
                                              ˢ)�"�r���L��U�Y�TI(@fu����Y���Z���x�Y+�Үµ-
                                                                                    

    .8d�P�+e�����4��N�    [�
                                                                                                                    ������+��b�Z]�6����D�/�(q�2��0Ӣ�Z�HeA�� ��Y
endstream
endobj
16 0 obj
<</Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /Arial-BoldMT
/Flags 4
/Ascent 905.27344
/Descent -211.91406
/StemV 76.171875
/CapHeight 715.82031
/ItalicAngle 0
/FontBBox [-627.92969 -376.46484 2033.6914 1047.85156]
/FontFile2 15 0 R>>
endobj
17 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/FontDescriptor 16 0 R
/BaseFont /Arial-BoldMT
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/CIDSystemInfo <</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (Identity)
/Supplement 0>>
/W [0 [750] 3 17 277.83203 21 23 556.15234 40 [666.99219 0 777.83203] 51 [666.99219] 68 [556.15234 610.83984 0 0 556.15234 0 610.83984 0 277.83203 0 0 277.83203 889.16016 610.83984 610.83984 0 0 389.16016 556.15234 333.00781] 93 [500] 188 [556.15234]]
/DW 0>>
endobj
18 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 320>> stream
x�]��n�0
        ��<E�ݡ��P6     !1�J�G�{ ��.QH���M;i� ���3v��n�ў�n�-x�k�L��I`g�hq���~%|ˡ�Q��<yӏQQ0�����6�����N����6_u�Z�ϒ�,��>dz��[7 �ѶmT�k?o��Oq�-0�̩9*�l'�u�Q��U��V�Q��|��{��9
��<IDR"�j$Ή^��#R�UD9Ҏ�d�%%垔))��Lk�'�쀔WH�KL$U���5�����
                                                       M<��NP��V��I�d�6���$�s����/G���>yu.��3XN__;�ŵ<�����
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /Arial-BoldMT
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [17 0 R]
/ToUnicode 18 0 R>>
endobj
xref
0 19
0000000000 65535 f
0000000015 00000 n
0000071700 00000 n
0000000154 00000 n
0000000191 00000 n
0000048619 00000 n
0000094566 00000 n
0000109180 00000 n
0000069862 00000 n
0000071953 00000 n
0000072008 00000 n
0000072056 00000 n
0000093141 00000 n
0000093375 00000 n
0000094148 00000 n
0000094698 00000 n
0000108095 00000 n
0000108334 00000 n
0000108789 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 19
/Root 10 0 R
/Info 1 0 R>>
startxref
109317
%%EOF
```